# Where did I get 0 in the output?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

My objective: Override the *process_sale* method so that 2% of each sale is added to rewards.

My problem: How did I get 0 in the output?

Exercise 5:
Use the parent classes to the left to help you solve this problem. The first parent is the **Person** class with some very generic information. The second class, **CardHolder**, is the class for a credit card holder. Create the child class **PlantinumClient**. This class inherits all of the attributes of both parent classes. In addition, the child class has the attributes *cash_back* and rewards. **cash_back** should be set to 0.02 and **rewards** should be set to 0. Override the **process_sale** method so that 2% of each sale is added to **rewards**.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, address):
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    
  def get_info(self):
    return f"{self.name} lives at {self.address}."
  
class CardHolder:
  def __init__(self, account_number):
    self.account_number = account_number
    self.balance = 0
    self.credit_limit = 5000
  
  def process_sale(self, price):
    self.balance += price
    
  def make_payment(self, amount):
    self.balance -= amount
    
# declare child class here
class PlatinumClient(Person, CardHolder):
  def __init__(self, name, address, account_number):
    super().__init__(name, address)
    super(Person, self).__init__(account_number)
    self.cash_back = 0.02
    self.rewards = 0    
  def process_sale(self, price):
      self.rewards += int( (price * 0.02) )

platinum = PlatinumClient("Sarah", "101 Main Street", 123364)  
  
#      Task:                        Expected output:                    
platinum.process_sale(100)      # n/a
print(platinum.rewards)         # 2
print(platinum.balance)         # 100
platinum.make_payment(50)       # n/a
print(platinum.balance)         # 50
print(platinum.get_info())      # Sarah lives at 101 Main Street.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the `process_sale`, but are not calling the original method. So no balance is added. You can see this by running the expected output (printing `platinum.balance` yields 0, but should yield `100`).

Answer (score 0):

```
# parent classes
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, address):
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    
  def get_info(self):
    return f"{self.name} lives at {self.address}."
  
class CardHolder:
  def __init__(self, account_number):
    self.account_number = account_number
    self.balance = 0
    self.credit_limit = 5000
    
  def process_sale(self, price):
    self.balance += price
    
  def make_payment(self, amount):
    self.balance -= amount
    
# declare child class here
class PlatinumClient(Person, CardHolder):
  def __init__(self, name, address, account_number):
    super().__init__(name, address)
    CardHolder.__init__(self, account_number)
    self.cash_back = 0.02
    self.rewards = 0

  def process_sale(self, price):
    self.balance += price
    self.rewards += int(0.02 * price)

platinum = PlatinumClient("Sarah", "101 Main Street", 123364)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).